# Firestore schema to support team roles

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, roles

Teams in my app can have members with different roles (owner, admin, member). I need to be able to enforce security rules based on those roles and perform queries on teams and users based on those access roles. I've read the group access control solution in the Firebase documentation (that implements team membership only, not team roles) and studied Firestore indexing and query constraints.

Below are schema options I've considered. I'm needing confirmation of my assumptions and advice on the best solution.

**Option 1**: The most natural choice would be to maintain a `team.roles` map (object) that maps uid (key) => "owner" or  "admin" or "member" (team role value). We can mirror this on `user.teams`. However since a uid is now a nested field name, when a query needs to find all members who are either "admin" or "member" I think we're forced to create a custom index **per uid**! You might make it work for a single where clause on the `roles.${uid}` field but the moment you add an additional `where` clauses or one the includes an `array-contains` condition I think you're forced to create a composite index per uid. Right?

If you have large lists of team members that can be a problem as you'll need to implement server side sorting with pagination in the query - which I think forces you to do custom indexing so in that cases this is a non-viable solution.

**Option 2** Replace the `roles` map with 3 object fields, one per role, each having uids as keys with value `true`. You can now use a simple query condition to find a "member", "admin" or "owner". You can also use a single `update()` to add/remove users from a role.

However **I think** you must once again avoid creating any composite indexes as they will include a `uid` so unlimited indexes required! Right?

**Option 3**: Replace the role map with 3 array fields, one per role, each containing a list of uid's. You can now use an `in` condition on a single role and can safely combine it with other conditions. This fixes the **per uid** indexing issue. Users can also be an owner or admin without being considered to be a member. However once you've used up the single `in` condition, you can no longer use another one on the same query so that can seriously constrain the types of queries you can now perform on the remaining fields (Firebase team please note the single `in` condition is a serious pain point that warps your schemas).

For Options 1 & 2, uids are nested field names so I think we also have an upper limit limit of 40,000 users (max index limit) in the system or maybe it's only 40,000 per team.  A benefit of this approach is that add/remove of users to roles are easy to do as single operations (no need to read then update, can just do a merge update).

Are there other best practice options?  Thanks for you help!

Comment: Can a user become a member of multiple teams (or only one)? If yes, I assume that a user can have different roles set per team, right? Maybe check this similar question (with a different approach) https://stackoverflow.com/q/62922737

Comment: yes .. they can also have different roles in each of those teams

Comment: Custom claims alone won't help me with some of the queries I need to perform .. like find me all members of a team having a given team role or find me all users who are members of a team with a given team role. So I must use Firestore team and user collections.  In fact my final solution will sync all user roles (dynamic team roles plus other fixed roles) from Firestore user objects into the Firebase Auth service as custom claims.

Comment: Did you come up with the solution as stated in your comment? Would love to see your final approach.

Comment: Still WIP .. but using Option 3 + Can sync a user to/from Auth server (either push `user.roles` to custom claims `roles` property OR pull an Auth server user if they are missing in `users` collection). So after updating team roles we push to custom claims and refresh user token to UI.  This keeps other queries performant and cheaper by removing `exists()` conditions in security rules.

Comment: We avoid `exists()` conditions in security rules by using `request.auth.token.roles` instead.

Comment: Subcollections may be a wiser path if you expect large lists of members